# Name of a packing problem similar to this?

Tags: algorithms

I couldn't search much about a problem I have.

There is a 1D array of zeros and ones. The objective is to pack all ones with the least number of containers. Each container is variable in length but has a maximum length limit.
Items in array cannot be moved.

For example, if the max length limit is 5, I would pack ones like:

[image: example]

I could only come up with a greedy solution, but I would like to know if there's an always-optimal one. I would appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your greedy solution is, but there is an easy greedy solution (here I denote $L$ the max length of a container):

```
Input: array of length n

i ← index of the first 1
while i < n do
   create a container starting at i of length max(L, n - i)
   i ← next 1 after index i + max(L, n - i)
```

Its complexity is linear in $n$, the length of the array. It is not quite difficult to see that it is optimal (the first 1 must be in a container, and we lose nothing to make that container the largest possible; that way the next created container can only be farther than in another solution, and so on).